# Translate string into reference to associative array index in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
[0] => [basketball][player]
[1] => [basketball][threes][player]
[2] => [basketball][home][leaders][player]
[3] => [basketball][away][leaders][player]
```

I want to translate each element into a reference to a certain element in an associative array:

```
$post['basketball']['player']
$post['basketball']['threes']['player']
etc.
```

Is there any way to automatically translate the former into the latter? It would be super convenient if so, and presumably super inconvenient if not, so I hope there's a way, but I don't know what it might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say something like this:

- Strip off the `[` at the start and the `]` at the end (using `substr`)
- Use `explode` to split the string by `][`
- Loop through the exploded pieces, using them as keys to the array.

So something like this:

```
$array = ..... // the big array
$str = "[basketball][player]";
$keys = explode("][",substr($str,1,-1));
$pos = $array; // PHP does a lazy copy, so there is no performance issue here
while($key = array_shift($keys)) $pos = $pos[$key];
// $pos is now your target element
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. I believe this would try to get `$pos['basketball']` and `$pos['player']` separately, when what I want is `$pos['basketball']['player']`. (This conclusion is based on copying and pasting this code into my app and trying it.)

Comment: You are correct, it gets `$pos['basketball']` followed by `$pos['player']`, but it assigns back to `$pos` so the result is `$pos['basketball']['player']`.